# Are 2 diagram homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Indeed there are many way to prove whether something are homeomorphic with each other. For the diagram below, it seems that they are not homeomorphic but i am not sure how to argue that.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the central point of the second diagram leaves a set with $6$ connected components; there is no point in the first diagram that has that property, and it *is* a topological property (i.e., one preserved by homeomorphisms).

Comment: I believe one could also say there are 4 points which don't disconnect the set on the left, while there are 6 such points on the right diagram. Is that correct?

Comment: @Clayton: Yes, that would also work: $4$ non-cut-points in the one, $6$ in the other (assuming that the line segments are closed).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so NUMBER of component sets is also a topological properties right?

Comment: @Mathematics: Yes, it is: homeomorphisms take connected sets to connected sets.